# what are the changes in mysql 8 result rowset case?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, mysql-8.0

when running

```
SELECT maxlen FROM `information_schema`.`CHARACTER_SETS`;
```

mysql 5.7 and mysql 8 produce different results:

- on mysql 5.7 the results row names are lower cased,
- on mysql 8 the results row names are upper cased.

NB : in the `CHARACTER_SETS` table, the comumn name is `MAXLEN` (upper cased).

Since I can't find a resource documenting it, my question is :

> what are the changes in mysql 8 result rowset case ?

Comment: note: I refused an edit in the question title because my question is meant to be general: I found ont symptom, I want to know what the cause is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MySQL 8.0 did change](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-improvements-to-information_schema/) the implementation of some views in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

> Now that the metadata of all database tables is stored in transactional data dictionary tables, it enables us to design an INFORMATION_SCHEMA table as a database VIEW over the data dictionary tables. This eliminates costs such as the creation of temporary tables for each INFORMATION_SCHEMA query during execution on-the-fly, and also scanning file-system directories to find FRM files. It is also now possible to utilize the full power of the MySQL optimizer to prepare better query execution plans using indexes on data dictionary tables.

So it's being done for good reasons, but I understand that it has upset some of your queries when you fetch results in associative arrays based on column name.

You can see the definition of the view declares the column name explicitly in uppercase:

```
mysql 8.0.14> SHOW CREATE VIEW CHARACTER_SETS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                View: CHARACTER_SETS
         Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mysql.infoschema`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `CHARACTER_SETS` AS 
  select 
    `cs`.`name` AS `CHARACTER_SET_NAME`,
    `col`.`name` AS `DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME`,
    `cs`.`comment` AS `DESCRIPTION`,
    `cs`.`mb_max_length` AS `MAXLEN` -- delimited column explicitly uppercase
  from (`mysql`.`character_sets` `cs` 
  join `mysql`.`collations` `col` on((`cs`.`default_collation_id` = `col`.`id`)))

character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
```

You can work around the change in a couple of ways:

You can declare your own column aliases in the case you want when you query a view:

```
mysql 8.0.14> SELECT MAXLEN AS `maxlen` 
  FROM `information_schema`.`CHARACTER_SETS` LIMIT 2;
+--------+
| maxlen |
+--------+
|      2 |
|      1 |
+--------+
```

You could start a habit of querying columns in uppercase prior to 8.0. Here's a test showing results in my 5.7 sandbox:

```
mysql 5.7.24> SELECT MAXLEN 
  FROM `information_schema`.`CHARACTER_SETS` LIMIT 2;
+--------+
| MAXLEN |
+--------+
|      2 |
|      1 |
+--------+
```

Or you could fetch results into a non-associative array, and reference columns by column number, instead of by name.

Comment: From what you say, I deduce this behaviour in the result rowset in mysql 5.7 and mysql 8  
 -1- *view* :column name case must be _forced_ using alias.
 -2- *table's column* name case is the one used in the SELECT

Comment: And, please, do you have a reference documenting this behaviour?

Comment: Did you see the link I provided in my answer? It's the official MySQL engineering blog. If you want something in the MySQL manual, you can search that as well as I can.

Comment: I (and a colleague of mine) did effectively search in the mysql manual, but we did found nothing. Thank you for both your time and your qualitative answer.

Comment: I discovered this difference testing a module I wrote against a MySQL 5.7 image on a pipeline. Locally, on a MySQL 8 container, querying `information_schema` for a table results in the rows array object(s) possessing a property named `TABLE_NAME`. However, On MySQL 5.7, the object possesses a property named `table_name`. I just test against both all upper and all lower in my result set (`if( (result?.[0]?.TABLE_NAME !== "x") && (result?.[0]?.table_name !== "x") )` ). It's nice knowing why I have to. Good explanation - first solid confirmation I found. Quickly, with solutions too - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no change in case sensitivity. If you check mysql documentation on identifier case sensitivity, both [v5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) and [v8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) say that field names are case insensitive:

> Column, index, stored routine, event, and resource group names are not case-sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases.

To me this seems more like a display difference.

Comment: As @Bill Karwin notes, the change is in the result rowset.

Comment: @Bruno those changes are irrelevant from mysql's point of view, since the field names are not case sensitive. The question only talks about mysql, nothing else. Stricktly speaking, Bill has answered a different question, that is only indicated in a deleted answer by someone else. The answer to the question above is: mysql's case sensitivity has not changed. It is your application code that is case sensitive.

Comment: I disagree: it changed in an unituitive way, but it did changed: the result rowset index names is part of the mysql's api.

Comment: @Shadow, you're answering the OP's literal question, but Bruno used terminology imprecisely. His problem is not whether MySQL is case *sensitive*. His problem is that the case of columns in the result set changed.

Comment: @BillKarwin then the OP should have updated the question. As it stands, your answer does not provide an answer to the posted question. It provides an answer to the question implied in a deleted answer.

Comment: @Bruno mysql's case sensitivity has not changed and that's the question you asked. Pls do not expect anybody to answer a question you did not ask. The moderators asked you and Pierre to update the question. You failed to do so.